# how can add python local module at ROS node?

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

my package at dev_ws/dev_ws/ORM/utils.py and in this file i need read_data() function.

and my publisher node at dev_ws/dev_ws/ and file name is P_webcam.py.

P_webcam.py is like this:

```
from ORM.utils import read_data    
code......
    
def main(args=None):
config_data = read_data()    
code....
```

and my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'dev_ws'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='***',
    maintainer_email='***@gmail.com',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'webcam_publisher = dev_ws.P_webcam:main',
            'webcam_subscriber = dev_ws.S_webcam:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

and my error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ORM'
```

how can i solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381718/how-can-add-python-local-module-at-ros-node?/) by [mahdigadget](https://answers.ros.org/users/77093/mahdigadget/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, you need to verify your whether you have installed Pandas library or not.
Once verified, you need to install ORM :

```
pip install orm
```

After installation your, error should be resolved.

---

Originally posted by [peterchondro](https://answers.ros.org/users/77733/peterchondro/) with karma: 16 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0